# bootstrap 4 radio button not conforming to padding

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, radio-button

I am having an issue where the Bootstrap 4 custom radio buttons are not not in-line with my left padding.

See below:

[image]

Here is my code for printing an item

```
<div class="p-4">
  <ul class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
    <!-- Option One -->
    <li class="w-100 side">
      <div class="d-flex pl-0 custom-control custom-radio align-content-start">
        <div class="pt-3 pb-3 mr-2">
          <input id="option-1" type="radio" class="position-relative custom-control-input">
             <label for="option-1" class="custom-control-label">
             <span>Option One</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
```

And a codepen to the full example:

https://codepen.io/Edon123/pen/LYPNbVv?editors=1100

How can I get my bootstrap input element to align with the padding?

edit: Essentially my problem is that the radio buttons are not being effected by the padding, as shown in the image. I want the radio buttons to be pushed by the padding.

Comment: both of your radio buttons available under `<div class="p-4">`.So use something like this. `<div class="p-4 ml-4">` which will aign in to whole `<div>. Is this what you expect. Or please let us know

Comment: not quite, but thank you @NipunTharuksha , I'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `.custom-control-label::before` refer to your custom radio has `position: absolute;` so the padding doesn't work with it.

```
.custom-control-label::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: .25rem;
  left: -1.5rem;
  display: block;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  border: #adb5bd solid 1px;
}
```

You can make it work by remove its `position: absolute;` and:

Option 1: change its `display` to `inline-block`.

Option 2: Add the below css to `.custom-control-label`:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/cuong97cc/pen/RwbaKVj?editors=1100)

Hope it help.

Comment: thank you for the response, I tried that in codepen, but it still does not seem to conform correctly

Comment: same issue that I see in original post, here is what I tried https://codepen.io/Edon123/pen/bGbpBzL?editors=1100

Comment: I copied the wrong part. It should be `display: flex` instead of `position: relative`.

Comment: And you need to remove `position: absolute` in `.custom-control-label::before`. I added the codepen, please check.